# Changing licenses - what about older versions of the code

Tags: licensing, open-source

Suppose I have a repository that is private (always has been), the code in this repository has been licensed under license A for a very long time with hopes of making the repository public in the future.

I now decide to make the code in this repository public, before I do this, I decide to change the license to license B.

What license (A or B) applies to the versions of code before the change to license B? - Note that the repository was not public before the change to license B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The license is whatever you publish it under. If you don't publish your code, it doesn't have a license.

If you publish a repository that includes old states where a different license is declared to be used, then it becomes slightly tricky. However, given that those who find your repository cannot tell that you didn't mean for the old versions to be under the old license, they can probably say in good faith that they believed to be in the right if they do use it as such.

Therefore, I would advise you to modify the repository (editing history) to change the license retroactively in all old versions before you make it public. There aren't any downsides to it, and it would remove the potential for misunderstandings and legal ambiguity.

Comment: This doesn't stop people who have received your software under the original license from redistributing under that same license, if the original license allows for redistribution. Only people who obtain the software under the new license are bound by the new license. That's fine in this particular case, since the repository was private and (presumably) no one actually received the software under the old license.

Comment: @ThomasOwens The repo was private before the license change, so nobody  could have received the software under the original license.

Comment: @sudoman Yes. My comment was mainly for other people who may find this. This answer is really only applicable in your particular case, and only if you are sure that (1) you are the only contributor and (2) no one else obtained the software under the original license.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Say I was using the `Apache` license first, and then the `GPL` license. Would I be allowed to modify the `GPL` license to say something like "All previous versions of code are now under this license", and would this solve the problem?

Comment: @sudoman: No, that wouldn't solve it. You can't retro-actively change the license. And modifying an existing license is also not advisable, especially if you aren't a lawyer.

Comment: What if changing the history isn't an option? - What can I do?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: I think your comment is confusing - the OP is not talking about  retro-actively changing a license of code he published before. This is about rewriting the history of a repo before it will be published, as this answer suggests (and it is IMHO a good suggestion).

Comment: @DocBrown but what if i cant change the history, because rebases change the commit hashes, and i have a lot of references to the hashes, i will lose all this. There must be another way...

Comment: @sudoman: the most simple solution is probably not to publish the history in public - why do you want to make this public at all? Just start with a fresh repo using the current version of your code and the new license.

Comment: @DocBrown I want to make it open source

Comment: @DocBrown Also, i'd like to use the current repo and not a fresh one because any contributions made to the fresh one, I'd then have to apply them to the current repo so that at-least one repo has the full history.

Comment: @sudoman: I guess there must be way to start something like a "public branch" with no history of your current repo, and still keep your private repo side-by-side. Sounds like a good question for SO - so I googled it and found [this older SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020553/push-a-branch-of-a-git-repo-to-a-new-remote-github-hiding-its-history). Looks to my that approach can solve your problem, still a little bit of work for you.